# How to groupby a fixed list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Assuming that I have a series made of daily values:

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2004', periods=365, freq="D")
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,101, 365), index=dates)
```

I need to use .groupby or .reduce with a fixed schema of dates.

Use of the `ts.resample('8d')` isn't an option as dates need to not fluctuate within the month and the last chunk of the month needs to be flexible to address the different lengths of the months and moreover in case of a leap year.

A list of dates can be obtained through:

`g = dates[dates.day.isin([1,8,16,24])]`

How I can group or reduce my data to the specific schema so I can compute the sum, max, min in a more elegant and efficient way than:

```
for i in range(0,len(g)-1):
    ts.loc[(dec[i] < ts.index) & (ts.index < dec[i+1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well from calendar point of view, you can group them to calendar weeks, day of week, months and so on. 
If that is something that you would be intrested in, you could do that easily with datetime and pandas for example: 
`import datetime` 
`df['week'] = df['date'].dt.week    #create week column` 
`df.groupby(['week'])['values'].sum()    #sum values by weeks`

Comment: Unfortunately isn't an option. All the [offset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) options are not suitable